# php variable wont be saved into database without including $parallellitem

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to save `$ManuellTagnavn` into the database without including `$parallellitem`. I use a HTML-input to get `$ManuellTagnavn`. Can someone figure what is that I am doing wrong? I want to save both, with and without `$parallellitem`. 
Please check following:

```
    <?php
 if(isset($_POST["SettInnM"]))

      {
      $pattern1 = "/^[A-Z]{1}$/";
      $pattern2 = "/^[0-9]{3}$/";
      $ManuellTagnavn = $_POST["TagnavnM"];
      $ManuellTagnavn = strtoupper($ManuellTagnavn);
      $annexaM = substr($ManuellTagnavn,0,2);
      $annexb1M = substr($ManuellTagnavn,2,-4);
      $sequenceNrM = substr($ManuellTagnavn,4,-1);
      $paralellItem = substr($ManuellTagnavn,7,8);
      $navn= $_SESSION['user'];
      $dato = date("d/m/Y");
      $prosjektID = $_SESSION["prosjekt_id"];


        $searcha = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['SettInnM']);
        $query = "select plass from annexa where plass = '$annexaM'";
        $resA = mysqli_query($db, $query) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),$query);
        $rowA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resA);


        $searchb1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['SettInnM']);
        $sql = "select format from annexb1 where format = '$annexb1M'";
        $resB1 = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),$sql);
        $rowB1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resB1);

        if ($rowA AND $rowB1 AND !preg_match($pattern1, $annexa) AND preg_match($pattern2, $sequenceNrM)) //AND preg_match($pattern1, $paralellItem) 
        {
        echo ("Hei");
        print_r($rowA);
        print_r($rowB1);
        $sql = "Select prosjekttag, prosjekt_id from tagnavn where prosjekttag = '$ManuellTagnavn' AND prosjekt_id = '$prosjektID'";
        $resultat = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultat) == 0)
        {
            $sql = "Insert into tagnavn(prosjekttag, startdato, prosjekt_id, opprettav)" //ENDRET AV ZLATAN 
            ."values ('$ManuellTagnavn', '$dato', '$prosjektID', '$navn')"; //ENDRET AV KAMALAN
            $resultat = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        }

      if(!$resultat)
       { 
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Maneult Kunne ikke sette inn i databasen")';
            echo '</script>';
            return;
       }
      }        
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see that you have added same variable two times.

**$ManuellTagnavn = $_POST["TagnavnM"];**

**$ManuellTagnavn = strtoupper($ManuellTagnavn);**

That's the main issue of conflicting your variables. Just rename one and try again. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't work. Still can't save into database without including $parallellitem

Answer (score 0):

Is the following what you want to achieve?

- If $paralellItem  is "validated" by preg_match, you put the info in the database with $paralellItem
- If $paralellItem wasn't "validated" by preg_match, you put the info in the database with $paralellItem

And your problem is that your script only does the second?

I'm a beginner, so I don't really get what your code does but I think you have to reconsider this line:

```
if ($rowA AND $rowB1 AND !preg_match($pattern1, $annexa) AND preg_match($pattern2, $sequenceNrM)) //AND preg_match($pattern1, $paralellItem)
```

You could try and do something like:

```
if ($rowA AND $rowB1 AND !preg_match($pattern1, $annexa)
    AND preg_match($pattern2, $sequenceNrM) AND preg_match($pattern1, $paralellItem)){
    // Here you have have included the $paralellItem in your if statement
}
elseif ($rowA AND $rowB1 AND !preg_match($pattern1, $annexa)
    AND preg_match($pattern2, $sequenceNrM)){
    // Here you didn't include the $paralellItem in your if statement.
}
```

or make an extra if for only preg_match($pattern1, $paralellItem)

Comment: The issue is this:
It wont save into the database without including $parallellitem in $manuelltagnavn. 
I want the solution to include both; with and without $parallellitem

Comment: What do you mean by including $paralellItem in $ManuellTagnavn?

Comment: When it is supposed to be saved in database;
The system won't let me save $manuellTagnavn if I don't include wiriting 8letters ($parallellitem is nr 8) in the HTML-input. If I only write 7letters the alert is given and nothing is saved in database.

Comment: If you don't get your script to output the line `echo("Hei");`, then the problem is in your `if()` statement. I'm talking about this line of code: `if ($rowA AND $rowB1 AND !preg_match($pattern1, $annexa) AND preg_match($pattern2, $sequenceNrM))`. The variable `$annexa` has not been declared. You declared `$annexaM` and `$annexb1M` but not `$annexa`.

Comment: Is there any possibility to debug the code to slowly check where there might be a mistake? 
Still can't save to database without typing 8 letters.

Comment: Please tell us what your script is doing rather than what it's still not doing. This refers to the first sentence of my previous reply. For debugging, you could use if/else statements. If the `if()` statement executes the command and the `else()` statement doesn't, you could echo the parameters from the `if()` statement inside the brackets of the `else()` statement. Eg: `if($variable == "1")` and `else{ echo $variable; }`

Answer (score 0):

There is two different lengths on $ManuellTagnavn, either 8letters or 7letters. Therefore, when using substr() it will be wrong to divide the string as if it was 8letters when it is only 7letters. One should check the length with an IF-statement. In this IF-statement the substr() should be customised for the given length on $manuelltagnavn.